# Reading URL in R and RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

When I type the following in RStudio it works fine:

```
nyt1 <- read.csv(url("http://stat.columbia.edu/~rachel/datasets/nyt1.csv"))
```

But when I type the same thing in the R console, I get this error:

```
Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open: HTTP status was '0 (nil)'
```

I have checked and rechecked a thousand times and everything seems to be exactly the same between RStudio and R (same versions, etc), so why the error?

Comment: For what it is worth, it worked for me in Rgui (Windows 7-64 bit). My guess would be proxy settings or network settings. Is the result of `setInternet2(NA)` the same under both scenarios?

Comment: Thank you Brian! setInternet2(NA) is True in RStudio and False in R. Do you know how can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: This may be useful. [link](http://www.r-bloggers.com/friday-function-setinternet2/)

Comment: Thank you guys, you are the best! Problelm solved!!

Comment: Sylvia - how about you post that link as an answer and then check the answer as accepted?

Comment: @BrianDiggs can you post your comment as an answer so Sylvia can accept it and we can close the matter?

Answer (score 5):

There can be differences in proxy settings or other network settings between RStudio and the R Console.  As one example, the use of the "internet2" option (defined on the command line when R is invoked) could differ. `setInternet2(NA)` on each platform will show the setting. If the result of that differs, that could be the source of the difference.

Comment: Any example to share?

Comment: @geotheory I do not have an example; I could not reproduce the error on my configuration. I got somewhat lucky guessing what the problem was in the comments, and, since I was right, I posted it as an answer.

Comment: It's ok thanks. I resolved it by running the script on Windows instead of Mac.

Comment: This worked for me, but I noticed that if you're using RMarkdown, Knitr uses a separate R console to compile, so you have to include setInternet2(TRUE) in your Rmd file, not just run it in the RStudio console.