# Read data from URL

Tags: r

How can I read data from following URL in R
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data
I tried

```
X <- read.csv(url("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data"))
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `url` in there.  Also, the file has no header, so say `header = FALSE`.

```
X <- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data",
              header = FALSE)
```

Comment: Getting following error: Error in file(file, "rt") : for https:// URLs use setInternet2(TRUE)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647207/reading-url-in-r-and-rstudio makes it sound like your internet settings are incorrect.  perhaps run `setInternet2(TRUE)` and then re-try

Comment: Tried. >setInternet2(TRUE)
> X <- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data", header = FALSE)
Error in file(file, "rt") : for https:// URLs use setInternet2(TRUE) Still not working. Same is the case on RGui

Comment: Try the suggestions in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028760/download-a-file-from-https-using-download-file  , like installing rcurl, or try just downloading the file.  It sounds like an internet connectivity problem, which is tough for us to solve. Google for your specific error and see if you can solve the internet problem.